Connect textbox in gridview and dropdownlist with a single datatable so that values can change in both at once without requiring a postback in ASP.NET
I would like to bind a textbox with dropdownlist by a single datatable or datasource like we bound controls in winform by using BindingSource. I don't want to use postback to do so.
My dropdownlist:
Dim ddlPack As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlPackaging"), DropDownList)
Dim dt as new Datatable()
dt=dl.getDefData(Resc.DL.FlagE.Packaging)     /////it return datatable with 5 columns
ddlPack.DataSource = dt
ddlPack.DataTextField = "EName"
ddlPack.DataValueField = "Id"
ddlPack.DataBind()

Above code works fine.
But I want to also bound textbox to same datatable of dropdownlist (that is  dt).
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" CssClass="form-control-sm" runat="server" Text="0" Width="64px"  MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox> =
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalWeight" CssClass="form-control-sm" ReadOnly="true" Width="84px" runat="server" Text="0" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtMul" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>    //////////This Textbox to bound
Munn(<asp:TextBox ID="txtMunn" CssClass="form-control-sm" runat="server" Width="72px" Text="0" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>)
Per KG Rate <asp:TextBox ID="txtPerKG" CssClass="form-control-sm" Width="98px" runat="server" Text="0" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>

The above dt contains 5 columns
SELECT [Id], [EName], [UName], [Multiplier], [Created Date]  FROM  PackagingT

One more thing these controls are in gridview which have multiple dropdown with different datatables so I can't bound gridview to datatable, Using VB.NET with .NET 4.0.
The logic behind all of this work is whenever a user change value from dropdownlist and enter value in txtQty, txtTotalWeight = txtMul * txtQty (These are textboxes Ids),  gives result (remember I don't need to use postback). If this can be done by JavaScript along with ASP.NET (VB.NET) it's ok for me.
I had tried:
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMul" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("Multiplier") %>"></asp:TextBox>

and
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMul" runat="server" Text="<%#  Container.DataItemIndex("Multiplier") %>"></asp:TextBox>



One more thing these controls are in gridview which have multiple dropdown with different datatables so I can't bound gridview to datatable,

Yes, you can bind the drop down to different data sources. And in fact, since you are starting to do "custom" GridView code, then I VERY much suggest you use code to bind and set the data source of the DDL anyway. (in other words, don't use nor bother with SqlData sources placed in the markup). SqlData sources in the markup are quick and easy, but the very instant you need custom control of the data binding, then don't use Sql data sources, as they are VERY limited, and worse yet you have no control over when such data sources trigger and fill out the controls. So, for a super simple page, then perhaps you can "risk" use of a SqlData source on a page, anything beyond a simple data binding, then SQL data source objects in the markup are not only messy, but lack flexibility.
It also not at a all clear why you want both a ddl, and a text box showing the same information on a given row. Since this is SUCH VERY strange request, then you probably should explain why and what the goal here is?
However, not knowing why you want both a ddl and text box to show the same information, let's just code up a working example.
First up be it desktop (FoxPro, MS-Access, vb.net or whatever), the approach to display such information is to use SQL relations, and thus most of the work will be done for you. In other words, do a left join of the table that drives the DDL, and no extra code is required to display such values. However, as noted, in your case you suggest that each row may have a different data source for the DDL, and hence the following approach is required.
First, we have to deal with the DDL.
When we fill the GV with data, then for each row of the GV, we need to:
Load up the DDL (set the data source). We THEN have to set the DDL to the current selected "ID" value for the given row. And if null/nothing, then of course we should set the DDL to show a "please select value" as a nice place holder. And of course if the current row has a null/empty value for the ID, then again we need to take that into consideration.
Also, like near every platform since the dawn of the PC computer revolution, those DDL's (combo boxes) tend to support 2 values. A hidden "pk" value, and then a 2nd column of a nice "display text". You not made it clear if that is your use case, but I'll assume as such, since that's again a super common setup.
One thing to keep in mind that un-like desktop in which I can bind a data source say with 5 columns to a DDL, but still only have the hidden PK value + 2nd column of text display, desktop DOES persist ALL OF the columns. Hence, if I bind say 5 columns to the DDL, I can later on by using of the index of the current DDL selected can retrive those other columns.
However, with the web based DDL's, then those additional columns are NOT persisted, and once the  databinding process is complete, then ONLY the 2 columns (PK + display text) are available.
Ok, so with the above in mind, then let's assume a list of some people, and we will use a DDL to select a hotel.
Of course in the data, the Hotel will be saved as a "pk id", but of course we want to display the hotel name text in the DDL.
Then we add your VERY strange request that beside the DDL, we will ALSO have a text box that display the current selected (text) value of the drop down.
Hence, this simple markup:
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
                OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                CssClass="table table-hover">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Width="110px"
                                Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Width="110px"
                                Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Width="110px"
                                Text='<%# Eval("City") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HotelName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHotels" runat="server"
                                DataValueField="ID"
                                DataTextField="HotelName"
                                onchange="mydropcopy(this);return false">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Crazy Repeated HotelName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Width="220px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn myshadow" />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Row" CssClass="btn myshadow"
                Style="margin-left: 20px" />
            <br />

Code to load the GV is thus:
Dim rstPeople As New DataTable
Dim rstHotels As New DataTable

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
        Session("MyTable") = rstPeople
    Else
        rstPeople = Session("MyTable")
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()


    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("", New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA 
                              ORDER BY HotelName"
        rstHotels.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

        cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * from People
                              ORDER BY FirstName, LastName"
        rstPeople.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        GridView1.DataSource = rstPeople
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim rDataRow As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem ' gets binding row data

        Dim ddlHotels As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("ddlHotels")
        Dim txtHotel As TextBox = e.Row.FindControl("txtHotel")

        ddlHotels.DataSource = rstHotels
        ddlHotels.DataBind()
        ddlHotels.Items.Insert(0, "Select Hotel")

        If rDataRow("Hotel_ID").ToString <> "" Then
            ddlHotels.Text = rDataRow("Hotel_ID")
            txtHotel.Text = ddlHotels.SelectedItem.Text  ' set text box to combo box
        End If

    End If

End Sub

So, note how we use the row data bind event (it runs for each row) to load up the DDL.
The result is thus this:

So, the only extra part is when we select the DDL, then we need to copy the selected (text) value to the text box.
And without a post-back, then we use JavaScript. This code (placed right after the GridView) is thus this:
(using jQuery here)
        <script>
            function mydropcopy(ddl) {
                var ddlHotels = $(ddl)
                var txtHotels = $("#" + ddl.id.replace("ddlHotels", "txtHotel"))
                var selectedText = ddlHotels.find("option:selected").text();
                var selectedValue = ddlHotels.val();
                txtHotels.val(selectedText)
            }
        </script>

As a "FYI" the above jQuery code also shows how to get both the hidden ID value of the DDL, and also the text value.
edit: Grabbing values from table without post-back
So, looking at above, it quite much is a proof of concept of what you are looking for.
However, let's assume I need the "rate" from the hotel drop down.
Our new markup:
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
                OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                CssClass="table table-hover">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Width="110px"
                                Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Width="110px"
                                Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Width="110px"
                                Text='<%# Eval("City") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HotelName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHotels" runat="server"
                                DataValueField="ID"
                                DataTextField="HotelName"
                                onchange="mydropcopy(this);return false">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nights">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNights" runat="server" Width="40px"
                                Text='<%# Eval("Nights") %>'
                                onchange="nightcalc(this);return false;"
                                ></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Night Rate"  >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="text-align:right">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="lblRate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NightRate", "{0:n0}") %>'
                                style="text-align:right"
                                EnableViewState="true"
                                >
                             </asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price"  >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="text-align:right">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="lblPrice" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("Price", "{0:n0}") %>'
                                style="text-align:right"
                                 EnableViewState="true"
                                >
                             </asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn myshadow" />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Row" CssClass="btn myshadow"
                Style="margin-left: 20px" />
            <br />
        </div>
        <br />

        <script>
            function mydropcopy(ddl) {
                var ddlHotels = $(ddl)
                var lblRate = $("#" + ddl.id.replace("ddlHotels", "lblRate"))
                var selectedText = ddlHotels.find("option:selected").text();
                var selectedValue = ddlHotels.val();
                var nights = $("#" + ddl.id.replace("ddlHotels", "txtNights"))
                var price = $("#" + ddl.id.replace("ddlHotels", "lblPrice"))

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "EditPeopleGrid.aspx/GetPrice",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({HotelID : selectedValue }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        lblRate.val(data.d)
                        rowcalc(nights, lblRate, price)
                    }
                });

            }
            function nightcalc(ctrl) {

                var nights = $(ctrl)
                var lblRate = $("#" + ctrl.id.replace("txtNights", "lblRate"))
                var price = $("#" + ctrl.id.replace("txtNights", "lblPrice"))

                rowcalc(nights, lblRate, price)

            }

            function rowcalc(nights, rate, priceresult) {
                // simple row calc - pass nights, rate and price controls

                priceresult.val(nights.val() * rate.val())

            }

        </script>

And the result now looks like this:

Note how we are free to tab around - edit any row.
The code behind is now this:
Dim rstPeople As New DataTable
Dim rstHotels As New DataTable

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
        Session("MyTable") = rstPeople
    Else
        rstPeople = Session("MyTable")
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()


    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("", New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT ID, HotelName,NightRate FROM tblHotelsA 
                              ORDER BY HotelName"
        rstHotels.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

        cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * from People
                              ORDER BY FirstName, LastName"
        rstPeople.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        GridView1.DataSource = rstPeople
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub

Sub GridtoTable()

    ' this sends gv rows back to rstData
    ' does NOT save/send back to database

    ' pull grid rows back to table.

    For Each rRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

        Dim RecordPtr As Integer = rRow.RowIndex

        Dim OneDataRow As DataRow

        OneDataRow = rstPeople.Rows(RecordPtr)

        OneDataRow.Item("FirstName") = TryCast(rRow.FindControl("txtFirst"), TextBox).Text
        OneDataRow.Item("LastName") = TryCast(rRow.FindControl("txtLast"), TextBox).Text
        OneDataRow.Item("City") = TryCast(rRow.FindControl("txtCity"), TextBox).Text

        Dim ddlHotels As DropDownList = rRow.FindControl("ddlHotels")
        If ddlHotels.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            OneDataRow.Item("Hotel_Id") = DBNull.Value
        Else
            OneDataRow.Item("Hotel_Id") = ddlHotels.SelectedItem.Value
        End If

        OneDataRow.Item("Nights") = TryCast(rRow.FindControl("txtNights"), TextBox).Text
        OneDataRow.Item("NightRate") = TryCast(rRow.FindControl("lblRate"), TextBox).Text
        OneDataRow.Item("Price") = TryCast(rRow.FindControl("lblPrice"), TextBox).Text

    Next


End Sub
Protected Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click

    Call GridtoTable()            ' send any edits back to table

    ' now send table back to database with updates
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * from People WHERE ID = 0"

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        Dim daupdate As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
        Dim cmdBuild As New SqlCommandBuilder(daupdate)
        daupdate.Update(rstPeople)
    End Using

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim rDataRow As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem ' gets binding row data

        Dim ddlHotels As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("ddlHotels")
        Dim lblNightRate As TextBox = e.Row.FindControl("lblRate")

        ddlHotels.DataSource = rstHotels
        ddlHotels.DataBind()
        ddlHotels.Items.Insert(0, "Select Hotel")

        If rDataRow("Hotel_ID").ToString <> "" Then

            ddlHotels.Text = rDataRow("Hotel_ID")
            'lblNightRate.Text = FormatNumber(rstHotels.Rows(ddlHotels.SelectedIndex)("NightRate"), 0)

        End If

    End If

End Sub


<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetPrice(HotelID As String) As String

    Dim sResult As String = "0"
    If IsNumeric(HotelID) Then

        Dim strSQL As String =
                "SELECT ID, NightRate FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID"
        Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = HotelID

        Dim dtHotels As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)
        If dtHotels.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            sResult = FormatNumber(dtHotels.Rows(0)("NightRate"), 0)
        End If

    End If

    Return sResult

End Function

Note close in above the web method that runs after you change a hotel (the ddl). This calls the web method to get the night room rate for that given hotel.
Note close how I used jQuery selectors to pick up the current row (this is a nice trick). Since each set of controls on a given row will be numbered, then we use the .replace method to simply "change" the name of the control, and the row numbering that ASP.NET applies to the controls thus will not matter.
Note close the save routine - it does a update of any and all rows - including additions, and achieves this in one database operation.

Thanks "Albert D. Kallal"; But i dont what to show Id or Hotel Name in textbox, their's a third column of Multiplier (to get total numbers of article in (Pack Or in Box) by typing no. of Qty) which will be shown in other Textbox.

take a look at my edit and further expanded example - I show how to update the row calculations without a post back, and I show how to save any and all grid edits in one database operation.

Thanks Albert D. Kallal Thats what i what ;
But can we do this without using ajax?
PLUS I Love your approach thanks.

Well, if the ddl list was the same for each row, then we could drop + add a hidden ddl on the page with id + rate, and then upon selecton of the hotel, then we take that row index and grab the rate from the hidden ddl on the page (outside of the gv). However, it really depends on how many choices in the ddl. I mean, a ddl is ok for maybe 30-50 choices tops. After that, the ajax example is a much better choice.
